# Condition for expression to have an integer solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the following expression
$$f(G_1,G_2,D)=\frac{\sqrt{G_1G_2}}{2}+\frac{(\sqrt{DG_1-(D-1)}-\sqrt{G_1})(\sqrt{DG_2-(D-1)}-\sqrt{G_2})}{2(D-1)}-0.25$$ for some positive integer $D$; $G_1$ and $G_2$ are real. 
Can a condition on $G_1$ and $G_2$ be derived such that $f$ is always an integer without resorting to Pell's equations?

Comment: Well to start $G_1G_2$ must be a square number which is a multiple of 2. You could work through like this to limit the possibilities of $G_1$ and $G_2$

Comment: I disagree. $G_1G_2$ can be anything as long as $f$ is an integer. You can verify it easily by using $G_1=121$, $G_2=542.2244$ and $D=29$.

Comment: Ah I see, I misread it and thought you said $G_1,G_2$ have to be positive integers too